# How to read or fetch the data by capturing the image?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in android. I'm building an app that when a user captures the image through the camera the app should read or fetch the data from the image and store that data in the database.

So I want the code in java or please help me with this topic.
Note: The image contains Person name, ID no, Gender etc.

Comment: You should give it a try and come back with an actual problem/error. Nobody is going to write your app.. not on this website.

Comment: you can use google vision library for convert image to text.Read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/getting-started).